# Select values from a data frame indexed to another data frame in a many-to-one relationship in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am building a program for simulating sequences of wind vectors (in base R).

I have a data set of parameters for six wind-generation mechanisms ('pars'),(I'll call them ellipses) and there are 5 parameters for each ellipse, thus 30 columns of parameters, plus other parameters that indicate the proportion of time (frequency, indicated by f.0, f.1...) each ellipse is in operation. There are 24 rows in 'pars', each identified by an 'hour' variable. The following codes generates a simulated 'pars' data frame

```
pars <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(24*42), 24, 42, dimnames=list(NULL, c(
'f.0', 'f.1', 'f.2', 'f.3', 'f.4', 'f.5', 'f.6',
'W.0', 'W.1', 'W.2', 'W.3', 'W.4', 'W.5', 'W.6',
'S.0', 'S.1', 'S.2', 'S.3', 'S.4', 'S.5', 'S.6',
'w.0', 'w.1', 'w.2', 'w.3', 'w.4', 'w.5', 'w.6',
's.0', 's.1', 's.2', 's.3', 's.4', 's.5', 's.6',
'r.0', 'r.1', 'r.2', 'r.3', 'r.4', 'r.5', 'r.6')
)))

jobFun <- function(n) {
    m <- matrix(runif(7*n), ncol=7)
    m <- sweep(m, 1, rowSums(m), FUN="/")
    m
}


 
   pars[1:24,c('f.0', 'f.1', 'f.2', 'f.3', 'f.4', 'f.5', 'f.6')] <- jobFun(24) # generate ellipse frequencies, summing to 1
    pars$hour <- 0:23                   # Add an 'hour' variable
    pars$p0 <- with(pars, f.0)  # change to make it zero if < zero!
    pars$p1 <- with(pars, f.1 + p0)
    pars$p2 <- with(pars, f.2 + p1)
    pars$p3 <- with(pars, f.3 + p2)
    pars$p4 <- with(pars, f.4 + p3)
    pars$p5 <- with(pars, f.5 + p4)
    pars$p6 <- with(pars, f.6 + p5)
```

I start by generating a sequence of POSIXct date-times for a single day, e.g, at 5 minute intervals ('sim'). For each date-time in 'sim', I need to select an ellipse and assign the parameters to the 'sim' data set. I have made additional columns in 'pars' with the cumulative probability of each ellipse, e.g., p0 = f.0, p1 = p0 + f.1, p2 = p1 + f.2, etc. I am going to select a different ellipse for each 5 minute time increment (then select the parameters corresponding to that ellipse). My difficulty lies in being unable to specify the appropriate value for p.

```
START <- ISOdate(2022, MONTH, 1, hour=0, min=0)
END <- START + (24*3600) - 1
tseq <- seq(from=START,to=END,by=300)
  sim = data.frame(tseq)
  sim$Ep <- runif(nrow(sim))    # Generate random vector Ep for ellipse picking
  sim$Enum <- with(sim, ifelse(     # number identifying ellipse to be used
        Ep < pars$p0[which(pars$hour == hour(tseq))], 0, ifelse(
        Ep < pars$p1[which(pars$hour == hour(tseq))], 1, ifelse(
        Ep < pars$p2[which(pars$hour == hour(tseq))], 2, ifelse(
        Ep < pars$p3[which(pars$hour == hour(tseq))], 3, ifelse(
        Ep < pars$p4[which(pars$hour == hour(tseq))], 4, ifelse(
        Ep < pars$p5[which(pars$hour == hour(tseq))], 5, 6)))))))
```

...
The result should be a vector (Enum) of integers between 0 and 6 identifying the ellipse to be used at each 5 minute time increment. My program only provides a correct answer at the 0th minute of each hour; there is something wrong with the statement

```
pars$p[which(pars$hour == hour(tseq))]
```

which ends up generating NA's for all the other 5 minute time increments in the hour. (i.e., there are 12 increments of 5 minutes in an hour, and the statement

```
which(pars$hour == hour(tseq))
```

brings up all 12 at once, instead of one at a time which is what I need here. Maybe I need a 'for' loop? Any suggestions for fixing, and for making the above code more compact, will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Seth, I think you might have forgotten to include the code to make `pars` in your reproducible example.  Do you mind quickly editing your question to include that line?

Comment: I will make a sample 'pars',

Comment: Great, thanks.  Also are you only interested in base R solutions or would you be open to a solution using the `dplyr::` package?

Comment: I'm more of a data.table user but yes, dplyr, absolutely

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the logical subscripting too complicated. All that is necessary is to change, e.g.,

```
pars$p0[which(pars$hour == hour(tseq))]
```

to

```
pars$p0[hour(tseq)+1]
```

and the value for p0 that is specific to the hour being simulated will be selected.

Spector (2008) "Data Manipulation with R" is helpful as usual.
Note that for question above, the 'lubridate' package is necessary for the hour() function, and MONTH must be specified (e.g., MONTH=4) to run the code